# Distributivity rule in propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I know that if you have $A\lor(B\land C)$ and apply distributivity rule you will get $(A\lor B)\land(A\lor C)$, but what if you have $A\lor\neg(B\land C)$? Can you apply the same rule, and if so what would be the result of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply distributivity to $A \vee \neg(B \wedge C)$, but note that by De  Morgan's laws 
$$A \vee \neg(B \wedge C) \equiv A \vee \neg B \vee \neg C.$$

Comment: Apply deMorgan's Law, then distribute, and apply deMorgan's again(twice).$$A\vee\neg(B\wedge C)~{= A\vee(\neg B\vee\neg C)\\=(A\vee\neg B)\vee(A\vee\neg C)\\=\neg(\neg A\wedge B)\vee\neg(\neg A\wedge C)\\=\neg((\neg A\wedge B)\wedge (\neg A\wedge C))}$$

Comment: I don't think you can distribute since you have OR both on outside and inside.